# create template for hibernate mapping files

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-tools

How can I create (if I can) a template file for my hbm.xml files to use while they are being created from JAVA class?

I am using Jboss Hibernate Tools 3.5.1 and Eclipse Indigo

You can find a detailed description below.

Thanks for your help.

---

My JAVA classes are coded carefully to represent the sql table. they all have the same syntax.

for instance lets say I have the following table in my db:

Tests (id int primary key, TestData varchar(255), Type int)

a class referring to this table is:

```
public class TestData {
    int id;
    String testData;
    int type;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getTestData() {
        return testData;
    }
    public void setTestData(String testData) {
        this.testData = testData;
    }
    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

When I create an automated hbm.xml file for this class it comes out as:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 12.Ara.2013 12:33:42 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.entegrator.framework.persistent.TestData" table="TESTDATA">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="&#221;D" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="testData" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="TESTDATA" />
        </property>
        <property name="type" type="int">
            <column name="TYPE" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

as you can see, my first problem is encoding.
what else I want to do is

- property column names and class table name should be converted appropriately
- id generator class should be "identity"

Answer (score 0):

You have to change them manually if you are creating `hbm` file using eclipse.

Other options are you can use annotations or create files our own to remove this extra headache.!!!

you can get more about the same at [Hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/)

Comment: maybe, but i cannot change my project's current structure. so if it is possible I need  xmls and I need a way to create them as I described